# Realm database - Notification when deleting an object

Tags: ios, realm

My question is simple: Is there some way for an instance of an object to be notified when it's about to get deleted?

I have a case where I have a property that is the path to an image stored on disk. I would like to delete this image whenever a realm object of that type is deleted.

Comment: I though Realm has this function

    `addNotificationBlock(block: (RealmCollectionChange<Results> -> Void)) -> NotificationToken`.

You can track deleted IDs in RealmCollectionChange object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer not to use KVO, you can take advantage of Realm's [Object Notifications](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#object-notifications).

A brief example would be:

```
var token: NotificationToken?
token = yourRealmObject.addNotificationBlock { change in
    switch change {
    case .change(let properties):
        print("Object has changed")
    case .error(let error):
        print("An error occurred: \(error)")
    case .deleted:
        print("The object was deleted.")
    }
}
```

just make sure to retain a strong reference to the token object since your notification block will be automagically unsubscribed by Realm as soon as it is released.

Answer (score 2):

You can use KVO to observe the `invalidated` property:

```
// a global context object to identify our observations
let myContext = UnsafePointer<()>()

class MyClass {
    func stuff() {
        object.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "invalidated", options: [.Prior], context: myContext)
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String!, ofObject object: AnyObject!, change: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, context: UnsafePointer<()>) {
        if context == myContext && keyPath == "invalidated" {
            print("\(object) is about to be deleted")
            object.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "invalidated", context: myContext)
        }
        else {
            super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
        }
    }
}
```

You may want to use something like [PMKVObserver](https://github.com/postmates/PMKVObserver) or [KVOController](https://github.com/facebook/KVOController) to simplify this, as using KVO directly can be unpleasant.